# Al detener una Web en Servidor IIS

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server

Tengo un proyecto en IIS (Windows Server) Pero si tengo alguien que esta mirando la página web no puedo subir el proyecto por lo tanto tengo que detenerlo y subirlo. Pero al usuario le sale una página de Error conforme no lo encuentra.

Se puede hacer mas amigable dicha página si la web esta detenida que se vea estamos en mantenimiento o alguna cosa asi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

de pronto puedes hacer una personalización de las páginas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracais Gustavo, me ha funcionado a la perfección